# How to split string from array with repeating fileds?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have got an input file with following syntax:

```
"ID","Company Name","AccountManager","Product","Support Type","Country"
```

Example:

```
"1","Company one","Surname Name / Phone/ Cell Phone ","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","29.10.2012 ► Type of support","Singapore"

"2","Company two","Surname Name / Phone/ Cell Phone ","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","31.10.2012 ► Type of support\n28.10.2012 ► Type of support\nn/a ► Type of support","Indonesia"

"3","Company three","Surname Name / Phone/ Cell Phone ","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version,"31.12.2012 ► Type of support\nType of support\nn\\a ► Type of support\n31.03.2013 ► Type of support\n25.10.2012 ► Type of support\nn\\a ► Type of support","USA"
```

The first company has only one product, the second company has 3 products - they are separated with `\n` (Product and Support Type) and the third company has 6 products.

In the output this string must be separate and repeat values of the columns:

`"ID","Company Name","AccountManager","Country"`, but `"AccountManager"` should have only Surname and Name, and column Support Type should be compared with today date - if date in support type different with today date in values from 27 to 32 days this columns must be in output file. If we have got `n/a` in the Support Type it should be missed.

The output should look like:

```
"1","Company one","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","29.10.2012","Singapore"
"2","Company two","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","28.10.2012","Indonesia"
"2","Company two","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","31.10.2012","Indonesia"
"3","Company three","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","25.10.2012","USA"
```

How can I do this in bash?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it using the following AWK script called "products.awk":

```
#/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=",";
    "date +\"%s\"" | getline curr_timestamp;
}

{
    split($3, account, "/");
    gsub(/ $/, "", account[1]);
    split($4, products, "\\\\n");
    split($5, supports, "\\\\n");
    for (i in products) {
        gsub("\"", "", products[i]);
        gsub("\"", "", supports[i]);
        split(supports[i], timesupport, " ");
        # ignore not available and support without date
        if (supports[i] !~ /n\\\\a*/ && supports[i] !~ /n\/a*/ && $2 !~ /\NULL/ && timesupport[1] ~ /[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/) {
            # formatting date
            split(timesupport[1], date, "\.");
            mydate = "date -d \""date[3]"/"date[2]"/"date[1]"\" \"+%s\"";
            # date to timestamp (using bash)
            mydate | getline timestamp;
            # timestamp is >= 27 days and <= 32 days
            if ((timestamp-curr_timestamp) >= 2332800 && (timestamp-curr_timestamp) <= 2764800)
                print $1","$2","account[1]"\",\""products[i]"\",\""supports[i]"\","$6;
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming that your data is in a file called data.txt, you can call this script from bash with this line:

```
awk -f products.awk data.txt
```

Using your sample file I got this output running the script:

```
"1","Company one","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","29.10.2012 ► Type of support","Singapore"
"2","Company two","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","31.10.2012 ► Type of support","Indonesia"
"2","Company two","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","28.10.2012 ► Type of support","Indonesia"
```

**EDIT:**

I only get 3 lines because of the last line does not fit in >= 27 && <= 32 condition (today is 29th Sep and your question was made 28th of Sep).

Finally we got it !!

Comment: Oh, thanks! Thaths good! But can you explain me how to make filter by value "n/a" and cut "AccountManager" to Surname and Name only?

Comment: And just and question - how to make filter by date - if date in support type different with today date in values from 27 to 32 days this columns must be in output file.

Comment: I added the line to filter n/a values. I will make an edit to solve Surname's stuff shortly

Comment: And just the last question - how to filter company name - in the file i have got some company with name "NULL" - in the output it shouldnt be. Thanks!

Comment: Add condition in `If` `&& $2 !~ /\NULL/` to exclude `NULL` companys names.

Comment: To split time I made construction `split(supports[i], timesupport, "\ >"); ` and add into print part `","timesupport[i]` but it works on some of companys.

Comment: One minute - I made some corrections - it works - making now construction if to time.

Comment: Have got some issues with time - I think that to compare two dates we must convert they to unix timestamp. I found commands to do this,  `"date +%s" | getline dateVal;` gives you time from unix timestamp, but to convert time from timesupport I have some issues - format is DD.MM.YYYY, but we need YYYY-MM-DD - i write sed construction `sed -n -e 's_\(..\)\(.\)\(..\)\(.\)\(....\)_\5-\3-\1_p"` in shell it works correct, but in programm - not.

Comment: rmunoz, excuse me, but i've got some questions - if we have got not a standart line in products such as `"155","CompFirm","John Smith / 5553 / +1 888 766 06 95","1) Soft1 ► (X2XXXX) ► 1.1.1-81c\n2) Soft2 ► (X1XXXX) ► 1.1.2-81c\n3) Soft3 ► (X9XXXX) ► 1.4.2-81c","1) 20.10.2012 ► 24x5 (consultation & s/w updates) (City)\n2) n/a ► unknown\n3) 24.11.2012 ► 24x7 (software updates only)","Russia"` - how to exclude `1)` and other numbers from products and updates?

Comment: And another question how to make a addition to number of days - date is complains on days of month that not 2 characters (he want `02`, but we give him `2`) and how to check that days of month is in 1 to 31, month is in 1 to 12, and year is in 1999 to 2025 - I wrote such construction `if (supports[i] !~ /n\\\\a*/ && supports[i] !~ /n\/a*/ && $2 !~ /\NULL/ )
&& ((date[1]) >= 1) && ((date[1]) <= 31) && ((date[2]) >=1) && ((date[2]) <= 12) && ((date[3]) >= 2000) && ((date[3]) <= 2025))` Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also I made writing to files - if date from 27 to 32 and field country is Russia then we write into file russian.csv, when field is Foreign we write into foreign.csv, when we have got some errors in date format we write into error.csv - i update code in 5 minutes.